# How do I change the default font color on paste on Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

Every time I paste a text onto a specific document on Google Slides, it changes its font definitions, including color to white, even if the color of the original text and the color of the text area where it's being pasted are black. I know how to [change the color](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2698842?hl=en) after (although it's hard to select it if the background is also white!), I want to know if there is a specific setting to change it *by default*.

Some details:

1. it works correctly on other documents and it was working ok before for this one; I'm not sure if I pressed a keyboard shortcut accidentally that triggered the issue
2. the issue happens on text copied from the web or even if it's a URL on Google Chrome
3. I've checked that the colors on the "master" are correct
4. This is the resulting "new" format after I paste the text (original is Arial black, 14)
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by refreshing (reloading) the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue that every time I paste text into Google Slides notes, it pastes it as font color white. (Note that I'm copying text from a text box in Google slides where the font is black). Very annoying.

One "fix" for this particular use case is that I changed the slide text box color to black. After doing that, when I copied the text and pasted it into the slide notes, it did not paste as white.

(Also, I tried refreshing the page but it did not change the font color back to black).